# Explain Chicken Problem solution

Tags: story

> You have 10 chickens as pets.
>   You opened their coop in the morning and 9 came out. You looked inside but the remaining one is not dead.
>   The 9 outside were eating their food but you noticed one of them had blue legs.
>   You thought it had become dirty and so it was not a big deal.
>   The next day, when you opened their coop, again 1 did not come out for food and 3 of the feeding chickens were eaten by the cat outside the coop.
>   The very next day, when you were away, 5 of your chickens were eaten by the cat while inside their coop.

So can you explain, why did the cat only eat 5 chickens in the end?

> Hint: There is more than one conclusion to the story. so, you have to figure out what happened to the chicken.
>
> Hint2: Blue legs is also a sign of disease in chickens

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I've edited the wording of your question to make it more readable. If there are any significant changes which affect the idea of the puzzle, please let me know.

Comment: The cat was full? 8 chicken in 2 days, thats a lot for one cat, leaving the rest for tomorrow... I think your question is too broad. If you have a specific conclusion in mind, please give more hints to lead us in the right direction.

Comment: @Bananenkopp don't take it personally. there can be more than one cat.

Comment: @Bananenkopp Just think if you are a detective or police and you have to solve any case then there can be more than one conclusion to the story. so you have to think about what can happen and need to give the possible solution according to the scenario in front of you. Here in the story either chicken can escape, chicken can die or chicken can be taken away. It is not too broad...

Comment: Looking at the accepted answer, your actual question was why only 5 were eaten *on the last day*???

Comment: @Sayed Mohd Ali A riddle should not have more than one correct answer but here It is based on your personal opinion which one gets accepted, not on the riddle itself. Therefore I asked you to narrow it down through hints to the answer you had in mind as this broad kind of questions are not "allowed" here.

Comment: @Astralbee because only 5 were the remaining alive chicken left in the coop.

Comment: 1st day 9 came out. so 1 of the chicken is either sick because when chicken are sick they stop moving much and there was one more chicken that was ill, the one outside. so the next day the 2 sick chicken either died or you have taken them/kept away for treatment. now there is only 8 chicken in the coop, from 8 of the feeding chiken 3 were eather by cat. so, on the last day only 5 chicken were left in the coop and they were aten by the cat.

Comment: @Bananenkopp the more than one conclusion means here that either chicken died, escaped or you kept them away. in all the cases you left with 5 chicken in the end. so it is no broad. if you just follow the story it is simple.

Comment: @SayedMohdAli If that's the case then my answer covered this too. I said that two were missing in action, and acknowledged that 3 had been eaten on the second day, leaving only 5 in coop. I know you're a new contributor and we have to be nice, but I am being kind when I say this wasn't good puzzle. I learned the hard way too, my first puzzle was slated. Since then I've created some better ones. You should lurk on the forum a bit longer, learn the kind of puzzles that are accepted before attempting another.

Comment: @Astralbee but your conclusion is totally wrong about other coops and another breed of chicken. I have not mentioned that there is any other coop at all. and you haven't asked either.  that is the only reason I have not accepted your answer and tried to give you more hint but your answer really impressed me but i can't upvote now. it was not accepted because it was not correct but that doesn't mean that it was not a good answer.

Comment: @SayedMohdAli Sure, I'm not at all bitter about getting it wrong. To be honest, I attempted an answer to be nice because it is one of your first puzzles. But now we have the "right" answer it is clear that your puzzle did not really have any focus and there is no single, logical answer to it. This is feedback.

Comment: @Astralbee it is not my first puzzle, and there is only one answer that there is only 5 chicken left in the end and cat eaten all of them. it was very straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On day one

> 9 living chicken went out of the coop
>  1 living chicken stayed in the coop (you looked after it)
>  From the 9 chicken 1 chicken got blue feet disease

On day two

> 1 chicken did not come out (you did not look after it this day) so i assume it died from hunger as it never comes out to eat
>  1 chicken with blue feet disease from day before also died today
>  3 chicken were eaten by the cat
>  this leaves 5 living chicken at the end of the day

On day three

> All 5 remaning living chicken were eaten in the coop by the cat.

On day four

> The cat dies of obesity because it has eaten to much chicken

Comment: yes, the other conclusion is that you have taken 2 sick chicken away for treatment with you...

Comment: @SayedMohdAli You've accepted this as correct but you've still given another conclusion? So basically there were multiple answers to this story, so how was it a puzzle?

Comment: 1st day 9 came out. so 1 of the chicken is either sick because when chicken are sick they stop moving much and there was one more chicken that was ill, the one outside. so the next day the 2 sick chicken either died or you have taken them/kept  away for treatment. now there is only 8 chicken in the coop, from 8 of the feeding chiken 3 were eaten by cat. so, on the last day only 5 chicken were left in the coop and they were aten by the cat.

Comment: @bananenkopp... for the cat part, it is not asked but it seems you are more worried about it. so, I will tell you I have not specified the cat size and chicken size. a big cat can eat lot of small chicken. and the cat loves to toy their hunt just like tigers, so that doesn't mean they need to eat whole of it. they can leave them untouched after killing them. and another possibility is the cat came on day one is other can and the cat came on day 2 is another. cat also sometimes take away their hunt with them for their babies...

Answer (score 0):

In your story, 2 chickens of yours apparently escaped, leaving 8 of your original 10. On one day you found 3 dead outside the pen, on another day you found 5 dead in the pen.

The reason why you only lost 5 is:

> Not all of the dead chickens were your pets.

The reason I think this is:

> On day one, you found that one of the chickens had *blue legs*. This is actually a different breed of chicken. Blue-legged chickens are *Ameraucanas*, the other similar looking breed is *Araucanas*. It sounds like, even before the cat turned up, your chickens were escaping and other chickens that were not yours were getting in, perhaps from a neighbouring pen? So 5 of the dead chickens were yours, the 3 others belonged to somebody else, and some are just MIA. This is perhaps why you wrote "3 of the feeding chickens were eaten", whereas you later specified that "5 of *your* chickens were eaten".

Comment: there can be more than one conclusion to the story.